# Pandas assign method error while trying to use lambda function

Tags: pandas

I am trying to change origin column to 'Europe' if it is europe else return the original column value as it is. I can do that using map, np.where etc but I need to do this with lambda function using assign method. I am getting the value error. Would be thankful if someone can help me fix this error.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
df = sns.load_dataset("mpg")
df.assign(origin = lambda df: 'Europe' if df['origin']=='europe' else df['origin'] )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following toy dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"rank": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "origin": ["usa", "jpn", "europe", "euro", "usa"]}
)

print(df)
# Output
   rank  origin
0     1     usa
1     2     jpn
2     3  europe
3     4    euro
4     5     usa
```

Here is how you could fix your code:

```py
df = df.assign(
    origin=df.apply(
        lambda x: "Europe" if x["origin"] == "europe" else x["origin"], axis=1
    )
)
```

Or even better:

```py
df = df.assign(origin=df["origin"].replace("europe", "Europe"))
```

Anyway, in both cases, you get:

```py
print(df)
# Output
   rank  origin
0     1     usa
1     2     jpn
2     3  Europe
3     4    euro
4     5     usa
```